# Sorting javascript array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, object

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to learn as much as I can but feel I have hit a brick wall with what I am trying to do.

My problem, I have an array of objects within each object is a shop object, in this is a "type of" repair object with properties of the cost of repairs.

How can I sort this by price? please see my code so far. I need to return the shop object in price order because I still need all the information of the shop but in order of price of repair depending on the selection made, so basically return shop object in an array in order of selection. It may not be possible I don't know, any ideas would be appreciated. I thank you in advance for your time.

```js
var vendors = [

  {
    mosShop: {
      samsung: {
        screen: 50,
        button: 10,
        back: 20
      },
      iphone: {
        screen: 10,
        button: 18,
        back: 1
      }
    }
  }, {
    davesShop: {
      samsung: {
        screen: 40,
        button: 5,
        back: 12
      },
      iphone: {
        screen: 18,
        button: 148,
        back: 11
      }

    }
  }


];
var arr = [];
//;
$('#phone,#repair').change(function() {



  var selectedPhone = $('#phone :selected').text().toString();
  var selectRepair = $('#repair :selected').text().toString();




  for (var i = 0; i < vendors.length; i++) {

    var mo = Object.keys(vendors[i]);
    var t = mo.toString()

    var price = vendors[i][t][selectedPhone][selectRepair];

    alert(price)


  }













});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="phone">
  <option value="samsung">samsung</option>
  <option value="iphone">iphone</option>
  <option value="mercedes">blah</option>
  <option value="audi">blah</option>
</select>
<select id="repair">
  <option value="screen">screen</option>
  <option value="button">button</option>
  <option value="back">back</option>
  <option value="audi">blah</option>
</select>

<div id="endresults">

</div>
```

`

Comment: please add how the result array should look like.

Comment: Did you search? [`[javascript] sort array objects nested property`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+sort+array+objects+nested+property)  --- one of those must be helpful.

Comment: As it is in my code but in order of the repair selected - lowest cost so if davesShop is lower then it should appear first in the sorted array of objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the array sorted according to the value of `selectedPhone` and `selectRepair`, you can use the native [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function like this-

```
function shopPrices(selectedPhone, selectedRepair) {
    return vendors.sort(function(a,b) { 
        var shopA = Object.keys(a)[0];
        var shopB = Object.keys(b)[0];
        return (a[shopA][selectedPhone][selectedRepair] - b[shopB][selectedPhone][selectedRepair]);
    });
}
```

Then you can simply call the function by passing the `selectedPhone` and `selectedRepair` values like follows-

```
var sorted = shopPrices('samsung','screen');
//Result -> [{"davesShop":{"samsung":{"screen":40,"button":5,"back":12},"iphone":{"screen":18,"button":148,"back":11}}},{"mosShop":{"samsung":{"screen":50,"button":10,"back":20},"iphone":{"screen":10,"button":18,"back":1}}}]

var anotherTest = shopPrices('iphone','screen');
//Result -> [{"mosShop":{"samsung":{"screen":50,"button":10,"back":20},"iphone":{"screen":10,"button":18,"back":1}}},{"davesShop":{"samsung":{"screen":40,"button":5,"back":12},"iphone":{"screen":18,"button":148,"back":11}}}]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Amazing thank you very much for your help and taking the time this is just what i was looking for. p.s There is a missing closing curly brace.

Comment: `Object.keys(a).toString()` should be `Object.keys(a)[0]`. Calling `toString()` on an array and using the result as property name is misguiding.